# How to round up in fraction part php

Tags: php, floor, ceil

I have some value like `2.3`, `3.6`,`3.8` now I want to get value as closest fraction.

suppose

when value is `2.3` then modified value will be `2.5` 
when value is `2.2` then modified value will be `2`

Comment: Then you need to look into PHP's `round()` function, and its optional flags http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php

Comment: ^ This is the answer. @ChrisMaggs why not add your comment as an answer?

Comment: Optional flags won't help here since `round()` returns always an integer.

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you want to round to closest "half integer".
If so, then you can use `round()` function but with a little modificators.

Because `round()` returns only integers, you need to modify your value before rounding and again after rounding in reverse way to make it work.

Since you want to round with 0.5, which is 1/2, you need to first multiply your value by 2, and divide it back after.

So the pattern here is:

```
$roundedVal = round($origVal*2)/2;
```

And examples from your question:

```
var_dump(round(2.3*2)/2); //2.5
var_dump(round(2.2*2)/2); //2.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to look into PHP's round() function, and its optional flags.

```
$myValue = -5;

echo abs($myValue);   //outputs 5
```